# How to create a report for members with no email address

Tags: reports

I would like to create a report of members that don't have emails.  How would I go about creating such a list in CIVICRM

Answer (score 5):

Use Search Builder:

- Go to **Search menu » Search Builder**.
- Set your Search terms to "Contacts" "Email" "Primary" "Is Empty" (see screenshot).
- Press **Search**.
  [image]